# Profile a web request end to end

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, php

I just recently moved an app from a single stack Linode configuration, to a full on Amazon configuration  as such: Load balancer, multiple app server, RDS database  instance.

My latency in the process went up by around 200-300ms.  I understand that having the app server and database server not on the same stack, will increase latency some.

How do I go about profiling a typical request to see where all the latency comes from, preferably with a nice break down.  This will allow me to optimize our weaknesses.  At the end of the day I want to be back around 100-150 ms on a request.

This particular  project is a Codeigniter project running on top of Apache & phpfpm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had very good success in using this application https://blackfire.io/

*Blackfire Profiler Fire up your PHP Apps Performance*

Easy to setup and currently requires the Chrome Browser but it will give you a break down of your entire application. It also supports SAPI & CLI which is quite nice too.

It's at least a tool to help you identify where you might have some performance issues.

Comment: Built by the team who brought us Symfony and Twig, incidentally.